# Creating a colorable, clickable grid (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a school project (the last one in my introduction to programming course). The html and css have been given. We need to allow the user to create a grid and then color boxes to make pixel art.

I've run into two issues.

1. My table isn't clearing when the user hits submit to create a new table, and
2. I can't get color into my grids.

I'd really appreciate any help that can be given.

```
// Select color input
let inputColor = document.getElementById ("colorPicker");

// Select size input
let table = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");
let iHeight = document.getElementById ("inputHeight");
let iWidth = document.getElementById ("inputWidth");


// Make the grid
let sPicker = document.getElementById("sizePicker");
sPicker.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  makeGrid()
});


// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
function makeGrid() {
  const height = iHeight.value;
  const width = iWidth.value;
  for (var w = 0; w < width; w++){
    const row = table.insertRow();
    for (var h = 0; h < height; h++){
      const cell = row.insertCell();
    }
  }
  let cPicker = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
  cPicker.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    cell.style.backgroundColor = inputColor;
    document.appendChild("cell");
    table.innerHTML = grid;
  });
}
```

The rest of the code is here:
https://github.com/shearda/pixelartmaker/

Answer (score 1):

By your words, I am assuming that you want that

1. When you Click on Submit it should reset the existing table.
2. When You change the color and click on any cell that cell be filled with selected color only.

I made little changes to js and html file,

1. Html file change: replace table with div of same id,
2. JS change you were attaching event listener incorrectly,

```
 /* you didn't attach any class to your cell so you will get null in this,
and getByClassName returns list of elements so you need to iterate over the list to attach event
*/
  let cPicker = document.getElementsByClassName("cell"); 
  cPicker.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    cell.style.backgroundColor = inputColor;
    document.appendChild("cell");
    table.innerHTML = grid;
  });
```

Give this a try

```js
// Select color input
let inputColor = document.getElementById("colorPicker");

// Select size input
let tableCanvas = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");
let iHeight = document.getElementById("inputHeight");
let iWidth = document.getElementById("inputWidth");


// Make the grid
let sPicker = document.getElementById("sizePicker");
sPicker.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    makeGrid()
});


// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
function makeGrid() {
  let table = document.createElement('table')
    const height = iHeight.value;
    const width = iWidth.value;
    for (let w = 0; w < width; w++) {
        const row = table.insertRow();
        for (let h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            const cell = row.insertCell();
            cell.addEventListener("click",event=>{
                event.preventDefault();
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = inputColor.value
            })
        }
    }
    let children = tableCanvas.childNodes? tableCanvas.childNodes:[]
    if(children && children.length===1){
        tableCanvas.replaceChild(table,children[0])
    }else{
        tableCanvas.append(table)
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Monoton;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <div id="pixelCanvas"></div>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice solution!!

Comment: lol, if you mean with the comment in the other answer me. I am not the OP.

Comment: sorry i am little bad with abbreviation.

Comment: The Original Poster

Comment: Oh thanks, its okay, our minds has similar idea. so i just posted the implementation

Comment: Thank you very much!  This solved my problem completely :) 2 questions: The code works without changing the table id to a div, but doesn't work without the "let table =" line (20). Why is it needed?

Also, are you able to explain the part from let children (line 33) down to the bottom?  It looks like the old empty cell is being replaced with a colored cell of the same value but why does it need to be in and if/else statement? 

Thank you again! Really appreciate your help

Comment: 1. If you use the table instead of div that' fine but due to just semantic convention, i was preferring div, table generally have rows and columns so parent i kept as div instead of table. It will work.

Comment: 2. I am assuming if you are removing `let table` then you are assigning parent table those rows, and columns which has id `pixelCanvas`. Then you need to remove all the rows from the table. logic need to be changed, so removing one child i.e. a complete table is better than removing all the children and adding new children (rows).

Comment: 3.  I kept in if else condition because there can be two case. 
Case 1:  initially the table might not exist in that case you need to just append the table to `pixelCanvas`. 
Case 2: The Table is already existing then if you try to append one more there will be two tables. But what you want is replace the existing table with new one. so thats why if else is required. Happy to help. Though your first question is little hard to explain with dom diagram of your code. but hope you are able to understand it

Comment: @AmandaSheard did you got this? If yes please accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I was able to solve your problem.
If you need more explanation, leave a comment below this answer so I can explain...

```js
let table = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");
let iHeight = document.getElementById ("inputHeight");
let iWidth = document.getElementById ("inputWidth");


let sPicker = document.getElementById("sizePicker");
sPicker.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  makeGrid()
});


function makeGrid() {
  table.innerHTML = '';
  const height = iHeight.value;
  const width = iWidth.value;
  let inputColor = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;
  for (var w = 0; w < width; w++){
    const row = table.insertRow();
    for (var h = 0; h < height; h++){
      row.insertCell().style.backgroundColor = inputColor;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Monoton;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why innerHTML tables content, why not create a new table in makeGrid()

Comment: actually the `innerHTML` appends any nodes(tags - elements) in an element that you want. And `innerHTML = ''`, removes all nodes in your table element. In this case, when you call `innerHTML = ''`, all `td`s and `tr`s will be remove and table will be ready to append new `td`s and `tr`s. for more explanations i want to refer you to [HTML DOM innerHTML Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).

Comment: @amanda-sheard, If your issue is resolved then I invite you to accept my answer, and if it was helpful (sounds like it was) then please also remember to upvote it as well (if you haven't already). Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help. With this code, its changing the entire table upon creating of the table. After generating an empty table, I want the user to be able to change individual cells to that color. Guarav's answer works for my purposes. But I still really appreciate you answering. Thank  you!